# How to access controller scope from dynamically created directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Basically I am trying to access controller scope property from directive's controller function. I am doing it through $parent property. It works fine for static directive but not for dynamically created directive. 
please have a look on my plunker

`Dynamic Directive`

In a plunker, when I click on folder with Id = 1. all goes good and folder path shows as "1 path". Same goes for folder with Id = 2.
But it does not work for dynamically appended folder with Id = n

I am somewhat new to angular. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

In light of the latest requirement:

> I am trying to call the directive function (i.e updateMap) from
>   controller.

You can use a **[Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)** to share variables between **Controllers** and **Isolated Directives**. In the example below, the Service holds the function that will be executed. Each directive when clicked will set the Service's function to it's own `updateMap()` function. Then the Controller in `onFolderPathClicked()` calls the Services `executeFunction()` function, which runs the previously set function.

script.js:

```
var module = angular.module('testApp', []);

module.service('updateMapService', function(){
  var updateMapFunction = null;
  this.executeFunction = function(){
    updateMapFunction();
  };
  this.setFunction = function(fn){
    updateMapFunction = fn;
  };
});
module.controller('crtl', function($scope, updateMapService) {
  $scope.onFolderPathClicked = function(){
    updateMapService.executeFunction();
  };
});
module.directive('folder', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      id: '@',
      folderPath: "="
    },
    template: '<p ng-click="onFolderClicked()">{{id}}</p>',
    controller: function($scope, $element, updateMapService) {
      $scope.onFolderClicked = function(){
        updateMapService.setFunction(updateMap);
        addFolder();
      };
      var addFolder = function() {
        $scope.folderPath = $scope.id + ":click here for calling update map";
        var el = $compile('<folder id="n" folder-path="folderPath"></folder>')($scope);
        $element.parent().append(el);
      };
      var updateMap = function() {
        alert('inside updateMap()..' + $scope.id);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="crtl">
    <div>FolderPath : <a ng-click="onFolderPathClicked()">{{ folderPath }}</a> </div>
    <folder id="1" folder-path="folderPath"></folder>
    <folder id="2" folder-path="folderPath"></folder>
  </div>
</html>
```

You could also move `folder-path` into a Service to save from passing it in as an attribute. The code smell being that passing it in as an attribute means doing so twice, whereas in a Service it means setting it and getting it once (code reuse).

Comment: Thanks Much Matthew:). I have one more doubt. I am trying to call the directive function (i.e updateMap) from controller. but I am unable to get the scope per directive. Please have a look on my plunker.[CallingControllerFnFromDirective](https://plnkr.co/edit/xPp650yO6eWZWwxvKPj3?p=preview). I am able to handle the click functionality of controller from directive (as you see alert is coming whenever I am going to click on text 'click here for calling update map') but correct scope of directive is not getting passed. It always show Id as 2. Could you help me on this

Comment: @BharatSewani I've updated my answer in light of the latest requirement.